# How to connect two separate Django project

Tags: html, django

I'm having two separate django projects one project is the dashboard and the another is data visualization project.
I need to connect or link my data visualization project into my dashboard project
I'm wondering how should i do that

Answer (score 0):

You have't mentioned the details of your questions. Still, I will try to answer it.

- You can take the help of APIs where you can process the data in the
  data visualization project and then call the end points from the
  Dashboard project and render the graph there.
- Secondly you have to
  make sure that both your projects are connected to same database and
  have the same models in both the project. Do migration from one project only for the sake of simplicity.

Please mention more details about your project and your use case for more specific answer